# Can I train an object detector using both thermal and RGB imagery in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision

I have a camera that can take thermal and RGB imagery and for detecting certain animals I want a classifier that will look at both the RGB and thermal imagery. Is it possible to use multiple image layers/channels for a tensorflow classifier?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a classifier with multiple layers, but the major issue here will be that your classifier will have to learn to detect animals for both thermal and RGB images and that is a tough ask for any classifier since RGB and thermal images are represented in very different ways.

Your problem seems to be a pretty standard area where [ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) can be used. I suggest you create **two** classifiers, one which trains on only RBG images and one that trains on only thermal images, whose results can be combined to give a single output (in your case, the animal that has been identified).